# Why can't see new add files in commit dialog with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I recall that, when I create a new file in a working copy, and `right-click` -> `SVN commit...`, I will see the new file in commit dialog.

Maybe look like this:
[image]

But recently, I don't know what's wrong, the commit dialog never show any new files that I just create right now.

Just look like this:

[image]

I have to add my new file by `aim at file, right-click, and TortoiseSVN, and Add...`

Answer (score 3):

- On the bottom left of the Commit dialog, there is a "Show unversioned files" option. Uncheck it.

  > If Show unversioned files is checked, TortoiseSVN will also show all unversioned files and folders in the working copy hierarchy,
  >   taking account of the ignore rules. This particular feature has no
  >   direct equivalent in Subversion, as the svn status command does not
  >   descend into unversioned folders.
- Check your `svn:ignore`'s. There is a chance that the ignore pattern affects some of your new files.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, go to the file in your file explorer, right-click and click on Add!
This will add the file to the versioned files.
This is equivalent to the `git add <file_name>` comment.